# Can't use Operator != for bool

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

I made operator for !=

```
PairXY operator != (PairXY a, PairXY b) {
PairXY res(a.x != b.x, a.y != b.y);
return res;
}
```

And i want to use it in this loop:

```
while (l.b!=l.a){}
```

But it gives me this error: could not convert 'operator!=(l.Line::b, l.Line::a)' to 'bool', i tried changing operator's PairXY to bool, but it stil didn't help.

Comment: Can you show the definition of `PairXY`?

Comment: It should probably look like: `bool operator!=(const PairXY& a, const PairXY& b) { return !(a == b); }` - in other words, reuse the `==` operator which is expected if you provide `!=`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**bool** operator != (PairXY a, PairXY b) { ... }

Answer (score 2):

The return type should be `bool`:

```
bool operator != (const PairXY & a, const PairXY & b);
```

Also, better make the parameters `const` reference, as I shown above.

Comment: Remember that if you don't put `&`, you would be invoking copy-constructor. The `const` makes it usable against const objects, if you have any.

Comment: @Shahbaz: Yes. That is why I put `&`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to return a pair of (probably) numbers, or a single boolean?

Usually, tuple-s are different (mathematically) when any component is pairwise different. So I would code something like

```
bool operator != (PairXY a, PairXY b) { return a.x != b.x || a.y != b.y; }
```

but perhaps you want something else (but then, I won't call that `!=`).

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: A free function cannot be declared `const`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is how your code should be.

```
class PairXY {
public:
    PairXY( int _x, int _y): x(_x),y(_y){}

    bool operator != (const PairXY a) {
        return(this->x != a.x && this->y != a.y);
    }
private:
    int x;
    int y;
};
int main ( int argc, char** argv ) {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would not work for this if `a` is `const` in the expression `a!=b`.